# vuetify grid nested row : understanding 12 cols system

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify.js, grid-system

I'm new on vue.js and vuetify and i'm playing with vuetify grid exemple.

I'm trying to get the same size for cols-4 and cols-7 cards and cols-3 and cols-5 cards

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THoot.png)

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QPt2.png)

```
<div id="app"><v-app id="inspire">
<v-container class="grey lighten-5">
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-card>
        .col-12
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">
      <v-card>
        .col-4
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card>
        .col-3
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="5">
      <v-card>
        .col-5
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="7">
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-card>
            .col-12
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="7">
          <v-card>
            .col-7
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <v-card>
            .col-5
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="5">
      <v-card>
        .col-5 Subsequent columns continue along the new      line.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

codepen : https://codepen.io/Biereblonde/pen/bGVPMKZ

thanks